# Find the Fourier transform of $f(x)=\alpha, ~\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: fourier-transform

Find the Fourier transform of  $f(x)=\alpha, ~\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

Solution:\begin{align*}
T(u)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}f(x) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{iux}f(x)dx+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty e^{iux}f(x)dx\\
&=\alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{iux}dx+\alpha\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{iu}\right]_{-a}^0+\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{e^{iux}}{iu}\right]_{0}^a\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{iu}-\frac{e^{-iua}}{iu}+\frac{e^{iua}}{iu}-\frac{1}{iu}\right]\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{2i\sin (ua)}{iu}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\alpha}{u}\lim_{a\to\infty}\sin (ua)
\end{align*}

But in the last line limit doesn't exist. So how do we find the Fourier transform of this function. Please help me out!

Comment: The Fourier transforms of constant functions are non-function distributions. For example, $f(x) \equiv 1$ are mapped to a multiple of the [Dirac $\delta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Use the linearity to deduce what $f(x) \equiv \alpha$ is mapped to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of Fourier Transform of a constant signal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808768/derivation-of-fourier-transform-of-a-constant-signal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Zerox commented.

\begin{align*}
T(u)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}f(x) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux}\alpha dx\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\alpha\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iux} dx\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\alpha\delta(u)
\end{align*}